# Error when running maildev - logger.info(`Recieved shutdown signal, shutting down now...`)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I get the above error when trying to run the `maildev` command in the terminal. I had it working before but it won't start since I needed to reboot my machine. I uninstalled and reinstalled but still no luck.

Here is the full error. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
$ maildev
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/maildev/index.js:92
    logger.info(`Recieved shutdown signal, shutting down now...`)
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/maildev/bin/maildev:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: When you type `node -v` in the command line, what version does it say? Please edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is a syntax error, not a shutdown signal. You're running an older version of Node that doesn't support [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which maildev is using in that logger message. So when it tries to log that line, Node crashes.

Template literals are an ES6 language feature that only newer versions of Node support. They act like strings that use backtick quotes, as opposed to single or double quotes. They allow you to evaluate expressions and variables directly inside the string.

```
console.log(`Hello ${name}, the ${job}!`)
```

The solution is to upgrade your version of Node to at least `4.0.0` or greater. If you can't upgrade Node then consider using an older version of maildev that doesn't use ES6 syntax like version `0.11`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I realized about the same time that it was a Node version issue but I'll accept your answer as the solution. I can't upgrade to Node to 4.0.0 at the moment so instead I fixed the problem it by installing maildev v0.11.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer to include the fact that downgrading maildev also works.